# Django filter datetime elements

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

I use django 1.11.2 for my project.
I had defined some models and all work right.

Now I need to get some data from one of my models by date. For example all entry which have month=8, month=9....

I have this, MyModel(....some fields...., created_date) and in models.py I have:

```
....
created_date=models.DateTimeField()
....
....
self.created_date=(datetime.now())
....
```

Created_date is a datetime field and its values are in this format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, for example 2017-08-31 14:25:58.

So, I see this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#month

And this will be perfect for me, but doesn't work.

From shell I write this:

```
>>> from project.models import MyModel
>>> from datetime import *
>>> MyModel.objects.all() ---> Work ok, I get all entries
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(created_date__month=8)
<QuerySet []>
```

In this case I get an empty Quertset.

Comment: It works. You have no record with month 7.

Comment: No sorry, was an example, I have many record with moth 6, 7 and 8, and don't work

Comment: print your datetime and check what month it is

Comment: Please write to us the output of your objects -> created_date

Comment: With USE_TZ = False work

Comment: @Vladyslav How I can get the output from my objects?

Comment: MyModel.objects.all()[0].created_date - for example

Comment: I get this: datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 29, 13, 50, 16)

Answer (score -1):

You may probably need to set `USE_TZ` into `False` in `settings.py` file

```
USE_TZ = False
```

If it is set as `True` i.e `timezone` enabled, then the `__month` lookup will not work